# executar script com permissão de administrador

Tags: scripting, powershell

tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
foreach($File in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath)){ 
        $ObjFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname, $CopyOptions);
    }
```

ele copia os arquivos para a pasta do windows, porém os usuários não tem permissão para fazer isso, estou tentando usar o seguinte trecho:

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script -Credential contoso\admin;`

mas não está funcionando, teria como guardar as credenciais em uma variável, para que ele não peça permissão a cada arquivo que for copiar?

script completo:

```
function getCredencial(){
    $usario = Read-Host "Usuario"
    $senha = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Senha"

    return New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $usario, $senha
}

$script = { 

    $FONTS = 0x14;

    $FromPath = "\\servidor01\arquivos\fontes\";

    $ObjShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;
    $ObjFolder = $ObjShell.Namespace($FONTS);

    $CopyOptions = 4 + 16;
    $CopyFlag = [String]::Format("{0:x}", $CopyOptions);

    foreach($File in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath)){ 
        $ObjFolder.CopyHere($File.fullname, $CopyOptions);
    }
}
$credenciais = getCredencial;
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script -Credential $credenciais;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisando pela net encontrei uma solução:

usando o comando `Get-Credential` é possivél fazer a mesma cosia.

atribuo as credencias a uma variável:

`$credential = Get-Credendial contoso\admin;`

e no `Invoke-Command` uso minha variável:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock $script -Credential $credential ;`

Obs: usando `Get-Credential`, aparecerá uma caixa de diálogo para inserir o usuário e a senha, e colocando `contoso\admin` apos o `Get-Credential`, só precisará digitar a senha, pois o campo usuário já estará preenchido.

Mais informações do Get-Credential [Aqui](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh849815.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Crie uma função que solicita o usuario, senha e que retorne um objeto credencial:

```
function getCredencial(){
    $usario = Read-Host "Usuario"
    $senha = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Senha"

    return New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $usario, $senha
}

#código principal....
$credencial = getCredencial
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script -Credential $credencial -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

`Read-Host -AsSecureString` troca os caracteres digitados por asteriscos dessa forma não exibe o conteudo da senha.

Referencias:

[Get FQDN Hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12268885)

[Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18144016)

Comment: testei essa solução, porém está dando o seguinte erro: `Invoke-Command: O Conjunto de parâmetros não pode ser resolvido usando os parâmetros nomeados especificados.`

Comment: @MeuChapeu, o conteudo de `$script` é o foreach? qual versão do powershell está usando?

Comment: editei a pergunta, coloquei o script como ele está agora.

Comment: @MeuChapeu, em `invoke-command` adicione o argumento `-ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME` que passa o nome da maquina.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou!